# How to model system over time in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, neural-network, frp

I am attempting to implement a neural network of sorts in Haskell.  This network is temporally aware, so timesteps are an important part of its function.  Without needing too many details, my general implementation of running the network over time is:

`foldM stepNetwork initialNetwork (zip images labels)`

The idea is that each timestep generates a new network that has learned one more image/label pair.  However, this approach leads to some gross data structures attempting to remember things from previous networks. Here is my hidden layer structure:

```
data HiddenLayer = HiddenLayer { hResponse    :: Response
                               , hOldResponse :: Response
                               , hNeurons     :: [YNeuron]
                               } deriving Show
```

and my current stepNetwork function is akin to:

```
stepNetwork (Network x y z) = Network newX newY newZ
  where
    newX = stepLayer x (hOldResponse y)
    newZ = stepLayer z (hOldResponse y)
    newY = stepLayer y (currentResponse newX) (currentReponse newZ)
```

I don't want to have to carry the old response along in the network.  Here is the relationship between the layers in the network, where X, Y, and Z are the three layers.

[image]

Since it is time sensitive, it seems like FRP would be a good way to model this relationship, but I'm just not sure how to model this in an FRP paradigm.  Any advice?

Comment: I don't understand why do you write `newY = stepLayer y (currentResponse newX) (currentReponse newZ)` but your diagram says `newY = stepLayer y (hOldResponse x) (hOldResponse z)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The architecture of a recurrent neural network `f` that observes an input vector `x` and has a state `h` is

```
f :: h -> x -> h
```

As you've already observed, if it has some side effect or output you can model it as

```
f :: h -> x -> m h
```

and run it with `foldM f`. Another typical thing to do is train an output layer that produces output `o` from `h`, either a separate network `g :: h -> o` or

```
f :: h -> x -> (h, o)
```

which is equivalent to `f :: x -> State h o`; if that has a side effect it's `f :: x -> StateT m h o`.

Training the network amounts to learning the function `f` and in some cases learning the type `h`. A recurrent network uses the same function `f` at all time steps. It's the job of training to *learn* which features from the past need to be remembered in `h`. You don't need "some gross data structures attempting to remember things from previous networks", the network learns to use `h` to remember pertinent things from previous time steps.

Any network or supervised training mechanism can be used to implement and learn `f`.

If you use a convolution instead of a recurrent neural network then you will need to remember a window of time that the convolution acts on. The easy way to do this is to present the entire window as the input vector `x'`. in neither case do you explicitly store any history in the implementation of the network `f`. A convolved network doesn't necessarily see a state carried forward from earlier time steps, it may be a function `f :: x' -> o`.

---

I think you're trying to go deeper, since you are presenting both the images and the labels (which I presume are examples for supervised learning). If you want to train `f` from a known set of examples then you don't need to model *learning from a series of experiences*.

If you want to model *learning from a series of experiences* you will have a state `t` of the machine training `f`, and a function `t -> typeOf(f)`. The type of the machine training `f` will depend on how the machine is connected to the real world. If the real world doesn't repeat experiences reliably, the machine will want to remember previous experiences (especially ones `f` performed poorly on) so that it can present those experiences to `f` for additional training. The machinery wrapped around the learning thing `f` should give `f` nightmares. It may want to remember a few experiences `f` does well on to make sure it doesn't lose existing performance, in which case `f` gets to enjoy some pleasant dreams.

In no case is it `f`'s job to remember previous experiences.

---

You want to go deeper? If the training machine needs to learn how to train things like `f` it would be trained over families of problems like the problem `f` is learning. The parameters of the training machine would be shared between problems, and the machine would learn which things to remember. As some level the machine would probably supervise itself, and machines of this kind which learn poor parameters and get stuck would be weeded out by some larger selectionary system that destroys incompetent machines.